# NSIncrementalStore to-one relationship fault fires immediately (eagerly loaded?)

Tags: ios, core-data, fault, nsincrementalstore

I noticed that the fault for a to-one relationship fires immediately when the fetch request is executed even though I'm not accessing the relationship. Particularly, a breakpoint in the method `newValueForRelationship:forObjectWithID:withContext:error:` is hit immediately in the NSIncrementalStore subclass.

```
- (id)newValueForRelationship:(NSRelationshipDescription *)relationship
          forObjectWithID:(NSManagedObjectID *)objectID
              withContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
                    error:(NSError **)error
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSIncrementalStore_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSIncrementalStore/newValueForRelationship:forObjectWithID:withContext:error:

The breakpoint is only hit when I access the relationship as expected for to-many relationships as expected (lazy loaded).

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

This is all about designing your own NSIncrementalStore.
Please go through doc [Incremental Store Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/IncrementalStorePG/ImplementationStrategy/ImplementationStrategy.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010706-CH2-SW18).

Here are extracts from the guide:

> If the backing data store makes to-one relationships readily
>   available, your incremental store returns to-one relationships in
>   newValuesForObjectWithID:withContext:error:. If your app and data
>   store are more efficient when all relationship fetching is deferred,
>   your store may instead return them in
>   newValuesForRelationship:forObjectWithID:withContext:error:.

Comment: I get that but I'm not sure how this answers my question.

Comment: Try setting breakpoint in newValuesForObjectWithID: and see if it is hit for the same to-one relationship, hopefully you will get your answer.

Comment: That breakpoint gets hit for every object even if a relationship is not accessed. That is my understanding. And, I am able to verify that this is the behavior.

Comment: Did it hit for same to-one relationship you were verifying? If yes, then you can deduce the fact that Core Data trying to make to-one relationship object readily available.

Comment: newValuesForObjectWithID:withContext:error: is not hit for a relationship. But, as per the document, it allows setting to-one relationships. If I set the to-one relationship to [NSNull null] in newValuesForObjectWithID:withContext:error: then the newValuesForRelationship:forObjectWithID:withContext:error: method is not called. So far it seems like the CoreData wants to make to-one relationships readily available through newValuesForRelationship:forObjectWithID:withContext:error: or newValuesForObjectWithID:withContext:error: But, it can't be deferred like to-many relationships.